# Using "Persist" annotation in Tapestry is causing Problems with RunJettyRun

Tags: eclipse, jetty, tapestry

I am going through the Tapestry beginner tutorial at: http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry-tutorial.html

I just downloaded the template project and tried running it as is.

The problem is adding the **@Persist** annotation to the property my application hangs indefinitely. I realized that it happens when I launch my application from Eclipse using a **RunJettyRun** configuration. If I run it form the command prompt with mvn jetty:run it works fine.

I notice that the RunJettyRun version on my machine does not match up exactly with the screenshots in the Tapestry tutorial. Mine allows you to select from three different Jetty versions:

Jetty 6.1
Jetty 7.5
Jetty 8.0

Version 8 doesn't launch at all. 6 and 7 have the hanging error.
Using Jdk1.7, Eclipse Indigo and Windows XP.

Comment: you might want to ask this one on the tapestry mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I realized that it happens when I launch my application from Eclipse using a RunJettyRun configuration. If I run it form the command prompt with mvn jetty:run it works fine.

I am a maintainer of RJR team ,  that sounds more like a RunJettyRun bug if you could run it well with "mvn jetty:run".

Because I am not familiar with Tapestry, if you could provide the reproducible war file and reproduce steps, and file a issue on RJR's tracker,

then I will try to check if there's anything we could do for it.

It sounds more like configuration conflict or version issue, but it's just a quick guess.

http://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/issues/list

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jetty 7 and it's working fine for me

- Did you try downloading the tutorial source code from GitHub and run that?
- Also note that any field with a @Persist annotation must not be initialized and should be private

[T5 tutorial source code on GitHub](https://github.com/hlship/tapestry5-tutorial)

Comment: dube- is there a difference between downloading the source code from github vs maven?