# Jetty won't work: Is there a way to purge it?

Tags: jetty

I'm a Jetty newb, but it's making life hell. First there was an Eclipse problem I described [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744446/using-persist-annotation-in-tapestry-is-causing-problems-with-runjettyrun). Rather than waste time on it, I decided to just run Jetty from the console. I started off importing a sample Tapestry project and was able to run it fine... the project is on the Tapestry page and is called **tutorial1**

I began work on my own project then and began introducing new functionality to it. At some point it stopped working. I tried backtracking my project to get it to a working state but every time I requested the home page it would just hang. At this point I still thought it was my fault, though I did think a more graceful error message would have been nice than the it attempting to load for a minute followed by a server timeout error.

I then shutdown jetty and attempted to load up the imported sample project using **mvn jetty:run** in my tutorial1 project directory. *it doesn't work either!* When I try going to localhost:8080/tutorial1 or the URL of my project the jetty console does show any output, almost as if it's not receiving the request.

I rebooted my entire machine but that doesn't help. I am not familiar with jetty architecture and am unsure if there is a way I can purge all my files from the jetty web application directory.

Any ideas?

**Cliffs Notes:**

- Downloaded Tapestry Archetype project with maven.
- Executed jetty from the command line using mvn jetty:run
- Started new project
- Executed jetty from the command line using mvn jetty:run
- Modified new project
- Error occurred, attempted fix and restarted Jetty (Ctrl + C, followed by mvn jetty:run)
- Jetty restarted, but did not seem to handle requests for any pages
- Tried starting jetty from Archetype project, experienced the same problem

Comment: I will respectfully say that jetty is not making your life hell, instead your problem is a lack of clear understanding in _what_ you are trying to do.  I see half a dozen different things going on here and its not really clear on where to begin, expect to say that rebooting your machine is not a solution for anything presented above that action you took.  As a stab in the dark, it seems that your primary goal here is to get Tapestry working, in which case I would advise you to seek a tutorial on working with that technology and follow it closely.

Comment: I mean, I am trying to deploy my application to Jetty and it isn't running. Sure that is probably due to an error I introduced into it, but now I cannot get ANY application to work in Jetty, including an OOTB demo app that was working before. I am guessing you either didn't read my question fully or you believe that something I did in one application could be affecting all the others. I don't know if/how that is possible, but if it is: please enlighten me! :)

Comment: How are you running Jetty? Is it always through maven? Or is it through some other method? Your description jumps all over the place so it's hard to follow exactly what steps you've taken.

Comment: I'll modify the original question to include the steps.

Answer (score 0):

If your project didn't deploy correctly, jetty won't serve any pages (they will either return 404 or some error in the 500s).

Look at the log folder and check if it is getting correctly deployed.